# Web API load Content file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api2

I work on a WebApi project and I don't understand how I can load a file I've created in my solution.
It's a basic json file I want to load and read.

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("file.json");
```

This code doesn't work. It search in the folder of the site, in IIS, but my file is not there.
How can I copy my file to be at the right place ?
I'm a bit confused about how it works.

I changed my file "Build Action" to 'Content' and "Copy to Output" to "Copy always"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to map the virtual path to the physical path on the server using `Server.MapPath`. Try this:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("jsonFileDirName"), "file.json");
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(path);
```

More info on `Server.MapPath` can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath?view=netframework-4.7.2